# Download from Firebase Storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using nodejs for the download of some files (mp3) from Firebase Storage, that I will send to the client.
I want to get blob file and then send to the client.
I read the docs and Firebase use refFromURL method to get the downloadable url.
But when I start the script, it says that refFromURL is not an url:

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin')
var serviceAccount = require('./api/admin.json')
firebase.initializeApp(optionFirebase)
var storageSongs = firebase.storage()
let linkSong = storageSongs.refFromURL('FILE_URL')
```

It's not an authentication problem because I use the same options for Realtime Database and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

`refFromURL` is a method provided by the Firebase JavaScript web client SDK.  It's not available in the Cloud Storage nodejs SDK for backends.

Comment: Ah, okay, Is there a way to get the downloadable URL from Cloud Storage? Because I need the blob data

Comment: UPDATE: I found a way to download a file into the memory:
`const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');
const file = myBucket.file('my-bucket');
file.download(function(err, contents) {}); //contents contain the file just downloaded`